# CloudKit. Is it possible to clear Caches\CloudKit\Assets?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I store images in CKRecord as CKAsset. Because of this, used a lot of disk space. Is it possible after fetch images from CKAsset, do the cleaning in at App\Library\Cashes\CloudKit\Assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to clean up those files via the CloudKit API.

CloudKit will manage that space for you and should clean up downloaded assets periodically or if a low disk space notification happens. Your application shouldn't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and I actually found a work around:

```
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true) as [String]
    let filePath = "\(cachePath[0])/CloudKit/Assets"
    do {
        let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(filePath)
        for file in contents {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtPath("\(filePath)/\(file)")
            print("Deleted: \(filePath)/\(file)") //Optional
        }
    } catch {
        print("Errors!")
    }
```

In essence, I manually navigated to the CloudKit/Asset folder, and retrieved all the CKAssets stored in there, then deleted them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  This works.  Although the caches directory is now located inside a directory with a UID.

I tried removing the whole cloudkit directory and this worked with seemingly no side effects.  iOS immediately rebuilt it, but reduced the payload of my app from 20Gb+ to 700Mb.

Although iOS takes care of this and ostensibly there's no reason to do it manually, the huge size of my data container was making it impossible to download locally for testing purposes.

Code updated for swift 5.x

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as [String]
        let filePath = "\(cachePath[0])/CloudKit"
        do {
            let contents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: filePath)
            for file in contents {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: "\(filePath)/\(file)")
                print("Deleted: \(filePath)/\(file)") //Optional
            }
        } catch {
            print("Errors!")
        }
```